Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed when running anchor test
This is a small test that I want to run on the devnet.
export async function createMintsTransaction(
  wallet: AnchorWallet
): Promise<anchor.web3.Transaction> {
  const [provider, program, seedUtil] = await getAnchorConfigs(wallet);

  const likeMintIx = await program.methods
    .createLikeMint()
    .accounts({
      likeMetadata: seedUtil.likeMetadataPda,
      payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    })
    .instruction();

  const retweetMintIx = await program.methods
    .createRetweetMint()
    .accounts({
      retweetMetadata: seedUtil.retweetMetadataPda,
      payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    })
    .instruction();

  return new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(likeMintIx).add(retweetMintIx);
}

describe("SolChirp Anchor tests", async () => {
  it("create the Like & Retweet mints", async () => {
    await anchor.web3
      .sendAndConfirmTransaction(
        connection,
        await util.createMintsTransaction(MASTER_WALLET),
        [MASTER_WALLET.payer]
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
});

the anchor toml -
[toolchain]

[features]
resolution = true
skip-lint = false

[programs.localnet]
sol_chirp = "2fjRTWqVzMHu77NdsdrE1KKkzs4GW8cQoCo4h1nQWCjM"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"


You have probably gotten your IP blacklisted. Give it a few days / switch to a new provider.
When I faced this error, I switched my provider/connection string to Helius, since program deployments worked just fine.
const connection = new Connection(
    `https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=${process.env.HELIUS_API_KEY}`
);


Thanks! doing this solved it!!
